# How to sum up multiple rows (list of rows) for a given column within scala without converting to dataframe

Tags: scala, group-by, aggregate-functions, user-defined-functions, scala-collections

I have a situation where i have list of rows with multiple columns and have to group by with a lookup key which is a unique column in all rows ..
I have to sum up values of a given column (say x) for all the rows from the lookup key (say lookup_1) in scala only using group by aggregate or any other method available ..
I can't convert to dataframe and use aggregate ..

I am sorry if I can't put code because policy doesn't allow so ..

Your quick help would be appreciated or guidance !!!

Comment: Maybe you can create a similar example that illustrates your problem?

Comment: Consider it as list of rows with 10 columns .. x,y,z etc ..with numeric values ... With a column who value is unique to some rows , say a with values a_1, a_2, and so on .. i have to sum values of columns x , y and z for all rows whose unique column value key is a_1

Comment: I apologize foe not able to giving it a proper code example ..